# How to make an Executable ".exe" file from a java Code

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, exe

I have an application that works fine and that I can execute from a .jar file. But I want to know how to make it runnable from any computer even if there is no JRE or the JRE version is not the good one. I thought about a .exe file but don't know how to do it.
I made my code with Eclipse and it use jxl,jdom and jfx librairies.
I tried to use Inno Setup 5.5.6 but when in Eclipse I run my build.xml as Ant Build it return me an error that says :

```
"'Launching JFX Build - Myapp' has encountered a problem.  
The achive : C:/Program%20Files/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64_3.104.0.v20150528.jar which is referenced by classpath, does not exist."
```

Comment: You can create exe file from eclipse by following steps in the given link.Refer [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-an-Executable-File-from-Eclipse)

Comment: There are lots of tools available in the market, some of them I am providing here. Please go through these links once, hope you will get solution.
1. [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)
2.[JexePack](http://www.duckware.com/jexepack/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX provides specific utilities for bundling your application as a native package, which is referred to as "Self contained application packaging". These utilities are provided as a command-line tool, or as ant tasks. Additionally, the common IDEs support this via wizards, either out of the box (NetBeans) or via a plugin (e(fx)clipse for Eclipse). The details of how to use any of these are far beyond the scope of a stack overflow question, but the basic documentation is available [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/jfxpub-deployment.htm). A tutorial for e(fx)clipse is [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial1).

Briefly, for e(fx)clipse, you should double-click the build.fxbuild file that is created in your project. Under the "Overview" tab, find the "Packaging format" option, and select "All" (or the specific type of package you want to create).

Note that you can only create a package targeted at the platform on which you are building, so if you want to create packages for windows, Mac, and Linux, you will need access to all three types of machine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, do you have any ideas about the error I mentioned on the subject ?

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late. I faced same problem a trick worked for me. Look at the given directory in the error message. It contains a space (C:/Program Files/...). Move your e(fx)clipse to another directory where the directory doesn't contains any space.

Not sure it will work your everyone or not but it worked for me.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

There are various tools that let you wrap your Java application in a Windows executable. Some tools are only simple installers, others allow you to bundle your application with a specific JRE version.

A widely used but commercial tool is [install4j](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html), but there is a bunch of other tools, such as [WinRun4J](http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: For a JavaFX application, you should create self-contained application bundles using the tools that are provided as part of JavaFX and ship with the JDK.